# windows phone 7 TextBlock TextWrapping not honored in listbox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, textblock

I have a listbox defined as :

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Width="468" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer Width="468">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

In the code, I create multiple textBlocks as the Listbox Items with textWrapping enabled in each textBlock.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < everyLine.Length; i++)
        {
            TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock()
            {
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                Name = "textBlock" + i,
                Foreground = textBrush,
                FontSize = 20,
                Text = everyLine[i]
           };

            this.myListBox.Items.Add(txtBlock);
        }
```

But, none of the text in any of the text blocks gets wrapped.

Can somebody please let me know if the above way of defining textBlocks in listbox is incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for the post, I had a similar issue and I had missed the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" property on the ListBox, your question helped find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for Derek's answer

Also, please be careful using the `<StackPanel>` in your ListBox. By default, the ListBox uses a `<VirtualizingStackPanel>` and this is very important as it uses significantly less UI resources (memory) when displaying long lists.

Comment: you mean we shouldn't use StackPanel as DataTemplate

Comment: no - I mean don't use StackPanel as an ItemsPanelTemplate if you are expecting the list to be long

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason why you are adding elements in code? By the looks of things you have a data collection, which you can set ast teh **ItemsSource** of the `ListBox` and then use an `ItemTemplate` to specify what each item should look like. Something like the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Width="468">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Note, that the default style for the `ListBox` already includes the `ScrollViewer` so there's no need to change the `ControlTemplate`. Because you've already fixed the width of the `ListBox`, the above should "just work".